# How to get rid of unnecessary signal in Photoluminescence Spectroscopy?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, optical-materials

[image]I am having some issues figuring out have to get rid of laser residues (might be) or scattering from the setup itself (please see attached pic).
In the lab, we have AUREA PIXEA 405nm laser, Horiba IHR550 spectrometer, and Mitutoyo 50X long WD objective.

Comment: Could you edit to make it clear what is the desired part of the spectra and add any other information that might help someone post an answer? Also, the screenshot shows 785 nm laser, but you say 405 nm laser. Which one is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.